# Determine which files are located in a physical area of an ext4 partition

Tags: partition, hard-disk, ext4, data-recovery, ddrescue

I managed to create an image of a 1000 GB ext4 partition on a dying HDD using ddrescue. The image is almost complete: only an area of about ~34 MB could not be read surprisingly close to the "middle" of the disk: 498396 MB - 498430 MB. I can mount the image, the filesystem is clean and I can see and open my files.

Since the partition was almost full, I am curious which files' contents were affected and thus damaged/lost due to the unreadable area. In other words, I want to get the list of files that are physically located entirely or partially in this area.

I would prefer a solution which uses basic Linux commands and utilities that can be found in a common rescue environment (I'm using UBCD right now for this), but a computer running Ubuntu Server with internet connection is also available and I can mount the image there if additional packages are needed to do this.

Comment: I know the other way around: `hdparm --fibmap <file>` will give you the physical location of the file on-disk. If no-one know a dedicated tool for the other way around, you could iterate over all files to check if any is in the damaged location.

Comment: @Hermann yeah that's what I figured. My shells scripting skills are beyond rusty but I'll write it if no such tool exists (I could not find one). I'll post an answer if I do this for anyone with the same problem in the future.